# Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found in Django 1.4.3

Tags: django

I know this question has been asked couple times but I cannot figure it out...

I am using Django 1.4.3 with the build authentication view. When I write the following code, I got this error:

```
<div id="divAuthbox">
  <p id="instructionTooltip">Sign in</p>
  <form action="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p class="label">{{form.username.label_tag}}</p>
    <p class="input">{{form.username}}</p>
    <p class="label">{{form.password.label_tag}}</p>
    <p class="input">{{form.password}}</p>
    <input class="loginButton" type="submit" value="login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />    
    <a href="/core/login_retrieval" class="padding" id="accessLink">Can't access your account?</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Note that I didn't put an extra quote in django.contrib.auth.views.login as I know that 1.4.3 doesn't need that. However, I still get the following error:

```
Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Sorry that I ask a duplicated question but I couldn't figure it out what's wrong with 1.4.3.

Thanks.

Comment: @Kintaro, Please check the answer that is appropriate for your question so that more people can find it in the future.

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your urls.py:

```
url('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

I am using Django 1.5

Answer (score 1):

the url template tag accepts url name, not view function path. you should add this view to the urlpatterns assigning the name='login' or so, later use `{% url login %}`